# using enums in jython

Tags: java, python, jython

Trying to use a Java Enum in Jython but I can't figure out how to use them.

when importing I see the enum listed as `BotInterface$MOVE` so I've put down the line

```
from amazebot2012.BotInterface import MOVE
```

In Java I would normally just use it as

```
bot.move(MOVE.FORWARD);
bot.move(MOVE.BACKWARD);
```

What is the Jython equivalent once I've imported it?

Trying `bot.move(MOVE.FORWARD)` gives me the error:

> Undefined variable from import: FORWARD

Comment: Does [How do you get a member of an enum in jython?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1894069) answer your question?

Comment: afraid not, I did come across that answer but it just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: bot.move() method comes from a java api that I'm trying to interact with. I just need to figure out how to set the value of that enum from jython

Comment: What happens when you `print(MOVE)`?

Comment: Possibly useful (scroll down to the second post): http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4677FDA8.5090508%40termalabs.com&forum_name=jython-users

Comment: print(MOVE) spits out <type 'amazebot2012.BotInterface$MOVE'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import and reference seem correct.

I suspect this is a bug in your editing environment, if you're using PyDev/Anapta:

http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7502

Comment: Thank you Matt! I had not even considered that the problem may be in my IDE. I ignored the problem and forced it to compile and everything runs perfectly.